# rails 1.9.3 `to_specs': Could not find railties Gem:load error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, webserver

I am get below error.

```
rails -v
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find      railties (>= 0) amongst [daemons-1.1.9, diff-lcs-1.1.3, expectations-2.0.0, faraday-0.8.9, faraday_middleware-0.8.8, ftpfxp-0.0.4, json-1.7.7, json-1.6.1, json-1.4.3, lumberg-1.1.1, metaclass-0.0.1, mime-types-1.24, mocha-0.12.7, multipart-post-1.2.0, mysql-2.8.1, rest-client-1.6.7, rspec-2.11.0, rspec-core-2.11.1, rspec-expectations-2.11.3, rspec-mocks-2.11.3, stomp-1.2.2, system_timer-1.2.4, systemu-1.2.0] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /home/adsudxuy/ruby/gems/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

My Gemrc file is as follows :

```
cat .gemrc
---
gem: --remote --gen-rdoc --run-tests
gemhome: /home/adsudxuy/ruby/gems
gempath: [/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1,
      /home/adsudxuy/ruby/gems]
rdoc: --inline-source --line-numbers
```

My bash profile is as follows:
    #start
    # .bash_profile

```
# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

#PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
PATH=$HOME/.gems/bin:$HOME/bin:$PATH

GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gems
GEM_PATH=$HOME/.gems:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

export PATH GEM_HOME GEM_PATH

#export PATH
#END
```

Also, for your reference, my gem env is as follows:

```
gem env
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
- RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-05-15 patchlevel 429) [x86_64-linux]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/user_name/ruby/gems
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /opt/ruby/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/user_name/ruby/gems/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
- ruby
- x86_64-linux
- GEM PATHS:
 - /home/user_name/ruby/gems
 - /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
 - :update_sources => true
 - :verbose => true
 - :benchmark => false
 - :backtrace => false
 - :bulk_threshold => 1000
 - "gem" => "--remote --gen-rdoc --run-tests"
 - "gemhome" => "/home/user_name/ruby/gems"
 - "gempath" => ["/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1", "/home/user_name/ruby/gems"]
 - "rdoc" => "--inline-source --line-numbers"
 - REMOTE SOURCES:
 - http://rubygems.org/
```

Please suggest what is wrong and how shouild i correct it.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what says `bundle show railties`? And I saw that .gemrc and .bashrc has different gempath sequences. This can make sense, please specify the only one of twos.

Comment: @rahul seems rails or its dependencies are not installed correctly. please show the gems list as well for details

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ bundle show railties gives same error as rails -v gives. Also, I have changed the path and it is same now still getting same error.

Comment: @G.B gem list is as follows                                       *** LOCAL GEMS ***

daemons (1.1.9)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
expectations (2.0.0)
faraday (0.8.9)
faraday_middleware (0.8.8)
ftpfxp (0.0.4)
json (1.7.7, 1.6.1, 1.4.3)
lumberg (1.1.1)
metaclass (0.0.1)
mime-types (1.24)
mocha (0.12.7)
multipart-post (1.2.0)
mysql (2.8.1)
rest-client (1.6.7)
rspec (2.11.0)
rspec-core (2.11.1)
rspec-expectations (2.11.3)
rspec-mocks (2.11.3)
stomp (1.2.2)
system_timer (1.2.4)
systemu (1.2.0)

Comment: provide please `which ruby`, then `which bundle`, and `which gem` then try install railties manually `gem install railties`

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ. Thanks a lot. gem install railties solved it. Now its working and showing the rail version.

Answer (score 8):

Try to observe the path to *railties* gem:

```
bundle show railties
```

And with `gem` app:

```
gem list | grep railties
```

If they are failed, try to install the gem manually:

```
gem install railties
```

If you are sure that the gem is presented, validate the GEM_PATH and GEM_HOME variables isn't broken by for example `rvm` app. Then set them properly to available on the system valid home, and paths of the gems, similar to:

```
export GEM_PATH=/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0
export GEM_HOME=/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try install generic ruby version :

`sudo apt-get install ruby-dev`

and then try,

`sudo gem install railties`