# Could not find 'railties'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, osx-yosemite

By mistake while trying to solve some bug i copy pasted the following command from SO into my terminal and after that my dev enviroment seems to be not working anymore.

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
```

When i try to run `rails` i get the following error.

```
/Users/harshamv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0) among 43 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/harshamv/.gem/ruby/2.1.0:/Users/harshamv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /Users/harshamv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:324:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/harshamv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in `gem'
    from /Users/harshamv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
    from /Users/harshamv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/harshamv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: All that does is change a directory in your home directory to be owned by you. And it's an NPM directory, unrelated to railties. Something else is wrong. Do a `bundle install`, if that doesn't work, when my `rvm` goes bad I just blow it away and start over.

Comment: blow it away in the sense?

Comment: This is related to this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23148951/rails-1-9-3-to-specs-could-not-find-railties-gemload-error

Comment: @HarshaMV In the sense of deleting my `.rvm` dir and reinstalling.